# postgres how to make conditional join

Tags: sql, postgresql, eloquent

I have json field that contains object or array of objects. I need to join one key from object if field contains only one object or use lateral join if there is array. I use `jsonb_typeof()` to determine whether it array or object and want to do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON
    (id) id,
    jsonb_typeof(field) AS type,
    CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof = 'object' THEN field->>'key' END
FROM
    test_table
    CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof = 'array' THEN lateral JOIN expression
```

is it possible to do something like this? At this point I get:

> undefined column error(jsonb_typeof)

... in when condition

Comment: That's too much of pseudo-code to get an accurate answer. Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your requirement

Comment: If you have to do a _conditional join_ something is going wrong. You should never have to do a conditional-join if your data-model is defined correctly.

Comment: It's bad enough storing JSON blobs in a database, it's even worse using the `JOIN` operator based on that JSON. You need to redesign your database to normalize those JSON blobs to **actual tables and columns**, otherwise you're in for a world of pain.

Comment: Conditional JOIN, sounds like a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

you can transform data in a subquery:

1. unnest the arrays with `json_array_elements`
2. `union` the unnested set with objects set
3. use this temporary set with the uniform object column in a normal join (by key or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

You can split this into two subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, jsonb_typeof(field) AS type,
    CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof = 'object' THEN field->>'key' END
FROM ((SELECT id, jsonb_typeof(field) AS type, field->>'key' as col
       FROM test_table
       WHERE jsonb_typeof(field) = 'object'
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT id, jsonb_typeof(field) AS type, field->>'key' as col
       FROM test_table LEFT JOIN LATERAL
            . . .
       WHERE jsonb_typeof(field) = 'array'
      ) 
     ) t
ORDER BY id, ???;
```

Note that when you use `DISTINCT ON`, you should be using `ORDER BY` as well.  Usually, there are additional columns beyond the `DISTINCT ON` keys to determine *which* row you want.